# How can I use transaction with pg-promise to insert data in two tables?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, pg-promise

I am using pg-promise library, postgres, Node JS and Express JS. I am trying to use transaction with pg-promise to insert values in table1 and use the returned id to insert values in table2 within the same transaction. Check my sample code below. When I run it in Postman, I got the error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

**SAMPLE CODE BELOW**

```
function addPost(req, res, next) {
  const queryKeyword = 'INSERT INTO table1 (post_type, created_on) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING pid'
  db.tx(t => {
    return t.one(queryPost, ['value1', 'now()'], x=>+x.pid)
        .then(pid => {
          const data = {
        author: req.body.username,
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        body: req.body.body,
        category: req.body.category,
        search_volume: req.body.search_volume
      }
      const insertPostText = `INSERT INTO table2 (pid, author, title, description, body, category, search_volume, created_on, updated_on) 
                                   VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9)`
      const insertPostValues = [res.rows[0].pid, data.author, data.title, data.description, data.body, data.category, data.search_volume, 'now()', 'now()']
            return t.none(insertPostText, insertPostValues);
        });
})
    .then(function () {
      res.status(200)
        .json({
          status: 'success',
          message: 'One Post added'
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return next(err);
    })
  }
```

Comment: It tells you that `res.rows` = `undefined`, and you are trying to access `res.rows[0]`.

Comment: Thanks @vitaly-t, I have worked it out.